# Phaser setting specific slots in an array didn't work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I've pretty much gotten past this problem by attacking to from a different angle, but I would like to know why my first approach didn't work.

In my game I had and array:

```
let inventory = [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null];
```

And to help manage it I made two methods.

The first one would put string into the array:

```
collect(item) {
    this.space = 0;
    while (this.space < 18){
        if (inventory[this.space] == null){
            inventory[this.space] == item;
            break;
        }
        else {
            this.space += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

And the second one checks if a string is even in the array:

```
has(item){
    this.space = 0;
    this.result = false
    while (this.space < inventory.length){
        if (inventory[this.space] == item){
            this.result = true;
            break;
        }
        else {
            this.space += 1;
        }
    }
    return this.result;
}
```

The has method works just fine, but for some reason, the collect method never worked. Despite using a similar system of loops and if statements, the method always left the array full of nulls.

Since the array called inventory was a global variable, I chalked it up to that as an explanation and switched to using the push function. But recently I tried using this approach again with an array that was local to its scene, but I got the same result: the string never went into the array.

I may be comfortable using the push function again, but I still wish to know: why did the collect method never work in the first place? Is there something in Phaser that prevents one from setting a specific slot in an array in this manner?

If it helps anyone, I'm using Phaser 3 in VSCode employing arcade physics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can and should use builtin functions in [javscript](/questions/tagged/javscript), this would also prevent errors.
*(the problem in the `collect` function is the typo `==` while setting the value, in the line `inventory[this.space] == item;`)*

In any case, with built in function's `collect` could look like this:

```js
collect(item) {
    let firstEmptyIndex = inventory.indexOf(null)
    if(firstEmptyIndex > -1){
        inventory[firstEmptyIndex] = item;
    }
}
```

And `has` would look like this:

```js
has(item) {
    return inventory.indexOf(item) > -1;
}
```

> *For more information to the function `indexOf`. [Link to documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)*